# Laravel policy remove pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project with laravel 5.5 and a create policy for my user not see what other user publish and my admin but went a create my `@can` in my blade i dont kwon how remove pagniation if the user does not have enough post .

```
Post::orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

and in my blade i do this

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
         @can('view', $post)
               <tr>
                   <th scope="row">1</th>
                   <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                   <td>{{$post->status}}</td>
               </tr>
        @endcan
@endforeach

{{ $jobs->links() }}
```

in my code i have superAdmin and Admin end this user can see all post so I can not do that

```
Post::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

and I do not want to make a code like that

```
if(Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin() || Auth::user()->isAdmin())
   Post::orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
else{
   Post::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
}
```

because i use this policy has a lot of place

Answer (score 1):

Policy can't remove pagination. Laravel hides pagination links if there is only one page of results.

Also, you have plenty of errors in the code that you should fix:

Instead of `$$post)`:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
```

Instead of `{{ $jobs->links() }}`:

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

Instead of this:

```
Post::where('user_id', $id)orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

Do this:

```
Post::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

Instead of `else{`:

```
} else {
```

Comment: cool thx in for my error in my code i am edit my question in my code is ok